# How to pass arguments to git from PKGBUILD?

Tags: arch-linux

In a `PKGBUILD` file its common to refer to a git URL directly, eg:

```
source=("git+${url}.git")
```

However, I would like to be able to pass arguments to the git command use to clone the repository.

Failing that is it possible to set environment variable git uses?

Is this possible? if sow how?

---

Note, the reason I want to do this is so the checkout can bypass pre-compiled libraries for MS-Windows & OSX, which arent needed for Linux builds.

Comment: I think this is related to the [dlagents and/or vcsclients](https://www.archlinux.org/pacman/makepkg.conf.5.html). I worked around the issue by locally specifying this in makepkg.conf: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154919/how-to-modify-a-pkgbuild-which-uses-git-sources-to-pull-only-a-shallow-clone/155052#155052

Comment: AFAIK modifying `makepkg.conf` doesn't help when I'm making a package for others to build via the AUR.

Answer (score 2):

The [man page for PKGBUILD](https://www.archlinux.org/pacman/PKGBUILD.5.html#_using_vcs_sources_a_id_vcs_a) covers how to use version control sources. While `makepkg` natively supports `git` sources, it does not provide a simple means of providing options to `git`. While it is possible to modify `makepkg.conf`, as I suggested in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154919/how-to-modify-a-pkgbuild-which-uses-git-sources-to-pull-only-a-shallow-clone/155052#155052), to override the default `git` behavior or specify a custom dlagent/vcsclient, the  [man page for PKGBUILD](https://www.archlinux.org/pacman/PKGBUILD.5.html#_using_vcs_sources_a_id_vcs_a) suggests:

> For other version control systems, manual cloning of upstream repositories must be done in the prepare() function.

In other words, don't add the git repository to the sources array, but rather do everything in the `prepare` function.

Comment: Are there any examples of a `prepare()` function that clones a repo? (with some sanity, not to barf on existing checkouts for eg).

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any options for this in PKGBUILD ([1](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PKGBUILD), [2](https://www.archlinux.org/pacman/PKGBUILD.5.html)). To work around this you can either create a fork or branch containing only the files you need.